# Find different elements individual or series in a list of non duplicate random numbers

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers, for example: `[4,5,6,8,229,230,250,170,118,119,120]`.

I'm trying to make a function that would give:

```
results = [4 to 6, 8, 118 to 120, 170, 229 to 230, 250]
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just sort the list, and split based on the difference.

Comment: Please clarify exactly how you want your *results* to be structured. What you've shown isn't valid in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question of how the sequences should be represented is unclear. One way would be to have the sequences as tuples within the list - i.e., just storing the first and last numbers in the sequence.

For example:

```
lst = [4,5,6,8,229,230,250,170,118,119,120]

lst.sort()

result = [lst[0]]

for x in lst[1:]:
    istuple = isinstance(result[-1], tuple)
    y = result[-1][-1] if istuple else result[-1]
    if x - y > 1:
        result.append(x)
    else:
        result[-1] = (result[-1][0], x) if istuple else (result[-1], x)

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[(4, 6), 8, (118, 120), 170, (229, 230), 250]
```

Comment: i've been experimenting with your answer, my app gave this list (list1= [212]) and i got (212,212) from your algortithm. Do you know what to change to have this output: [212]. (NB: The format you gave me is perfect)

Comment: I have tested this with an input list of *[212]* and the output is as expected - i.e., *[212]* I think you must have transcribed it incorrectly. Please check